# ¿Obtener versión de aplicación Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

Yo tengo el nombre de mi aplicación en `strings.xml` de la carpeta `res/values`:

```
<string name="app_name">Liturgia+</string>
```

Yo quisiera cambiar ese valor, agregando la versión actual de la app. Suponiendo que la versión actual es `1.3`, quisiera algo así:

```
Liturgia+ (v. 1.3)
```

Mi pregunta es si sería posible **obtener de forma automática el valor actual de la versión dentro de un recurso xml**, de modo que el valor se actualice sólo al cambiar la versión.

Comment: Entiendo que quieres extraer el numero de version que esta en el string con algo asi como con expresiones regulares. O me equivoco?

Comment: No @Einer, lo que quiero es traer desde el gradle el número de versión actual para ponerlo al lado del nombre de la aplicación... No sé si hay alguna forma de hacerlo en el xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dentro de tu `build.gradle` puedes definir el `versionName`, el cual es un String que indica la versión:

```
android {
        ...
        versionCode 1
        versionName "(v. 1.3)"
        ...
    }
```

estos valores también los puedes definir dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jorgesys.ussd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="(v. 1.3)">
```

solo recuerda que la configuración del `build.gradle` siempre sobreescribe la del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

**Dado lo anterior, puedes obtener el valor de `versionName` de esta forma**:

```
public String getVersionName(Context ctx){
    try {
    return ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

otra forma es simplemente (requiere que el proyecto este construido):

```
public String getVersionName(){
     return BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
 }
```

El valor tipo String  de  `versionName` lo puedes concatenar al nombre de tu aplicación.

---

Incluso puedes definir como  `versionName` el valor `Liturgia+ (v. 1.3)` , ejemplo:

```
android {
        ...
        versionCode 1
        versionName "Liturgia+ (v. 1.3)"
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Jorge solamente decir que si se usa `gradle` no es necesario enrollarse con `PackageInfo` para obtener la versión. Podemos cambiar las **seis líneas de código** a la que nos obliga `PackageInfo` por esto simplemente: **`BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`**. Genial, ¿no?. De todos modos, yo lo que quería saber era si había alguna forma de tenerlo disponible como un string del xml, pero parece que no es posible. La solución que más se acerca es lo que dices al final de tu respuesta... poner `nombre de app + version` en `versionName` del gradle.

Comment: Si muchas gracias!. Tenerlo dentro de Strings.xml yo lo realizaba hace tiempo, una entrada del nombre de la app y otra para la versión pero ahora lo tomo directamente de lo que defino en el build.gradle/manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no es posible realizar eso, lo que puedes hacer es obtener el versionName desde el gradle usando codigo, y despues concatenar en codigo pero no en XML

Para obtener el versionName usas el siguiente código:

```
    try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        String version = pInfo.versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```