# Como saber la versión de liberación (build/version) de mi app con kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Quiero mostrar en mi app la versión actual de la misma con el lenguaje kotlin.
El código que tengo en java es este:

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Esto en java funciona bien.  ¿Cómo hago lo mismo en kotlin?

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución:

```
    try {
            var pInfo = applicationContext.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
            var version: String = pInfo.versionName
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Versión: $version",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }catch (e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Gracias de todas maneras a quien quiera aportar.
Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente forma

```
val code = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
val name = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME

Log.i("prueba", "Code App $code Code Name $name")
```

Espero te funcione

Comment: Gracias.De hecho no conocía esta forma de hacerlo y si funciona perfecto.

Answer (score -1):

La forma de obtener la versión es [similar a como se realiza con Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112188/obtener-versi%C3%B3n-de-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-en-strings-xml), en Kotlin es:

```
var versionName : String = applicationContext.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionName;
```

de esta forma se obtiene el valor del `versionName` que definimos dentro de nuestro `AndroidManifest.xml` o de nuestro archivo `build.gradle`.

Si se tiene definido en ambos archivos, el valor que tiene prioridad es el definido dentro del archivo  `build.gradle`.

Comment: Recomendable para los -1 es recomendable agregar la razón, esto para mejorar las respuestas, en caso de algún error..