# ¿como obtener el codigo de la version de app en playstore?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Como podría obtener el código de la versión de mi aplicación que se encuentra en play store?.
De antemano gracias.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Obtener versión de aplicación Android en strings.xml?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112188/obtener-versi%c3%b3n-de-aplicaci%c3%b3n-android-en-strings-xml). Ese valor se lee en realidad desde el gradle. [Ver la excelente respuesta de @Jorgesys ofreciendo varias posibilidades de hacerlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112298/29967).

Comment: Por ejemplo: `int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;` Y para el nombre de versión: `String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;`

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano,El codigo que necesito obtener es el que tiene la aplicacion alojada en playstore,y no el que tengo localmente.

Comment: Es el mismo código. Cuando subiste la App a Play Store se subió con ese `VERSION_CODE`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano , devjav no tienes el código , puedes revisar  el versionName dentro de tu archivo build.gradle o androidmanifest.xml

Comment: @devjav no tienes acceso al código? puedes entrar a la playstore?

Comment: @Jorgesys , si tengo acceso lo que pasa es que lo necesito para compararlo contra mi aplicación ya instalada. Esto para saber si esta o no desactualizada