# Como verificar si hay disponible una actualización en PlayStore?

Tags: android-studio

Buen dia, como puedo hacer para que cada ves que se abra la app, esta verifique si hay actualización en la play store?

Aclarando mi pregunta, es una aplicacion que he desarrollado, lo que necesito es que cuando entre a la apliacion muestre un Dialog fragment notificacando que hay una actualizacion, de lo contrario no tiene que mostrar el Dialog

Comment: Una aplicación desarrollada por usted? o una instalada de un tercero?

Comment: Agrega más detalles o lo que has investigado y responde por favor lo que pregunta J.Rodriguez @SaúlHernández , saludos!

Comment: play store es quien te notifica si hay o no una actualización.
En otro caso puedes hacer una pequeña comparacion interna en tu app con un numero ejemplo mi app instalada en el telefono tiene la v1.0 y en un espacio , de lado , podrias colocar una comparacion entre versiones , "si la versioninstalada es < a la del playstore" muestra un icono que indique de deba actualizar...
no se java , pero creo que es eso lo que debes hacer, en tu base de datos ingresa la version a ser comparada entre el servidor y tu dispositivo
Listo!

Comment: Es una aplicacion que he desarrollado y que ya tengo en la tienda

Comment: @SaúlHernández gracias por actualizar tu respuesta, he agregado una respuesta, revisala y comenta dudas, en lugar de mostrar el Dialog fragment que abra Google PlayStore y tu aplicación a actualizar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actualmente la aplicación Play Store lo realiza pero si lo deseas realizar desde tu aplicación:

Puedes obtener la versión realizando un GET a la página de tu aplicación y buscar el valor de "Current Version" en el contenido HTML. Como ejemplo esta aplicación:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.baba

si revisas el código html encontrarás "Current Version" y posteriormente su valor `2.19.1` (mayo 2018).

En internet puedes encontrar varias versiones para realizar esto para realizarlo en tu propia aplicación, un ejemplo es utilizando el parser html [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/download), para esto se debe agregar la dependencia dentro del archivo `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
   ...
   ...
}
```

es importante recordar que la comparación se debe realizar entre versiones únicamente se puede realizar con versiones definidas que tienen este tipo: x.x.x.x.x.x

por lo que debes estar preparado para realizar la comparación, por ejemplo

```
1 es menor 2.19.1
2.20 es mayor a 2.19.1
2.19 es menor a 2.19.1
3.0 es mayor a 2.19.1
etc
```

Para esto puedes usar este Asynctask que realiza lo anteriormente descrito:

```
class updateApplication extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String newVersion = null;
        try {
           Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()  + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get();
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d("updateAndroid", "Document: " + document);
                Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
                for (Element ele : element) {
                    if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                        Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                        for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                            newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newVersion;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {
        super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);
        Log.d("updateAndroid", "Current version: " + currentVersion + " PlayStore version: " + onlineVersion);
        if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {
            if(isUpdateRequired(currentVersion, onlineVersion)){
                Log.d("updateAndroid", "Update is required!!! Current version: " + currentVersion + " PlayStore version: " + onlineVersion);
                openPlayStore(); //Open PlayStore
            }else{
                Log.d("updateAndroid", "Update is NOT required!");
            }
        }    

    }

    private void openPlayStore(Context ctx){
        final String appPackageName = ctx.getPackageName();
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        }
    }

    public boolean isUpdateRequired(String versionActual, String versionNueva) {
        boolean result = false;
        int[] versiones = new int[6];
        int i = 0, anterior = 0, orden = 0;
        if(versionActual != null && versionNueva != null){
            try{
                for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                    versiones[i] = 0;
                }
                i = 0;
                do{
                    i = versionActual.indexOf('.', anterior);
                    if(i > 0){
                        versiones[orden] = Integer.parseInt(versionActual.substring(anterior, i));
                    }else{
                        versiones[orden] = Integer.parseInt(versionActual.substring(anterior));
                    }
                    anterior = i + 1;
                    orden++;
                }while(i != -1);
                anterior = 0;
                orden = 3;
                i = 0;
                do{
                    i = versionNueva.indexOf('.', anterior);
                    if(i > 0){
                        versiones[orden] = Integer.parseInt(versionNueva.substring(anterior, i));
                    }else{
                        versiones[orden] = Integer.parseInt(versionNueva.substring(anterior));
                    }
                    anterior = i + 1;
                    orden++;
                }while(i != -1 && orden < 6);
                if(versiones[0] < versiones[3]){
                    result = true;
                }else if(versiones[1] < versiones[4] && versiones[0] == versiones[3]){
                    result = true;
                }else if(versiones[2] < versiones[5] && versiones[0] == versiones[3] && versiones[1] == versiones[4]){
                    result = true;
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                Log.e("updateApp", "NFE " + e.getMessage() + " parsing versionAct " + versionActual + " and versionNew " + versionNueva);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("updateApp", "Ex " + e.getMessage() + " parsing versionAct " + versionActual + " and versionNew " + versionNueva);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

para obtener la versión actual en tu aplicación instalada lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
public String getVersionActual(Context ctx){
    try {
    return ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

[¿Obtener versión de aplicación Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112188/obtener-versi%C3%B3n-de-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android)

Por lo tanto cada vez que se abra la aplicación puedes llamar el Asynctask que realiza el trabajo de esta forma:

```
new updateApplication().execute();
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Estoy viendo tu respuesta, pero no me encuentra el metodo getPackageName(); otra cosa, en la linea MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), seria el nombre de mi actividad principal?

Comment: getPackageName(); necesita el contexto, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName()  si estas dentro de una activity no se necesita, pero si no lo tienes puedes obtenerlo por ejemplo mediante getApplicationContext(),  de esta forma getApplicationContext().getPackageName()

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la respuesta de Jorgesys, lo he hecho en Kotlin:

Ponemos dentro del archivo `build.gradle` lo siguiente:

```
    dependencies {
       ...
       implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
       ...
       ...
    }
```

Creamos una clase nueva llamada `ServiceUpdateApplication`:

```
internal class ServiceUpdateApplication : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    val TAG = "ServiceUpdateApplication"

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String? {
        var packageName = params[0] //getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
        printLog(TAG,"PACKAGE NAME: " + packageName)
        var newVersion: String? = null
        try {
            val document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
            if (document != null) {
                printLog(TAG,"Document: $document")
                val element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version")
                for (ele in element) {
                    if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                        val sibElemets = ele.siblingElements()
                        for (sibElemet in sibElemets) {
                            newVersion = sibElemet.text()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        printLog(TAG,"NUEVA VERSIÓN: " + newVersion.toString())
        return newVersion

    }
}
```

Por último, en la actividad donde queramos utilizarlo añadimos los siguientes métodos:

```
    /**
     * Comprueba la versión actual con la del Play Store. Si la del Play Store es superior la abre
     * para que puedas actualizarla.
     */
   fun checkVersion() {
        var currentVersion = getCurrentVersion() //Obtiene la versión actual del dispositivo
        val getContact = ServiceUpdateApplication()
        val onlineVersion : String = getContact.execute(applicationContext.packageName).get() //Obtiene la versión de la aplicación en el Play Store

        Utils.printLog(TAG, "Current version: $currentVersion PlayStore version: $onlineVersion")
        if (!onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {
            if (isUpdateRequired(currentVersion, onlineVersion)) {
                Utils.printLog(TAG, "Update is required!!! Current version: $currentVersion PlayStore version: $onlineVersion")
                openPlayStore() //Abre la ficha de la aplicación en el Play Store
            } else {
                Utils.printLog(TAG, "Update is NOT required!")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene la versión de la aplicación instalada en el dispositivo
     */
   fun getCurrentVersion(): String {
        try {
            return applicationContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(applicationContext.packageName, 0).versionName
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return ""
        }
    }

    /**
     * Abre la ficha de la aplicación en el Play Store para poder actualizarla
     */
   fun openPlayStore() {
        val appPackageName = applicationContext.packageName
        try {
            ContextCompat.startActivity(applicationContext, Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appPackageName")),null)
        } catch (anfe: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException) {
            ContextCompat.startActivity(applicationContext, Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")),null)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Comprueba la versión actual con la del Play Store
     * @param versionActual Versión actual instalada en el dispositivo
     * @param versionOnline Versión de la aplicación en el Play Store
     * @return Devuelve true si hay una nueva versión para actualizar
     */
  fun isUpdateRequired(versionActual: String, versionOnline: String): Boolean {
    var listVersionActual = versionActual.split(".")
    var listVersionOnline = versionOnline.split(".")
    val max = max(listVersionActual.size, listVersionOnline.size)
    var i = 0
    while (i < max){
        try {
            if(listVersionActual[i].toInt() < listVersionOnline[i].toInt())
                return true
        } catch (ex : IndexOutOfBoundsException){
            ex.printStackTrace()
            if(listVersionActual.size < listVersionOnline.size) return true
        } finally {
            i++
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Además, he simplificado el método `isUpdateRequired`. Espero que os ayude.

Comment: Como se haria para mostrar la fecha de la version instalada y la fecha de la version del playstore?